# argument of HAVING must be type boolean, not type integer

Tags: sql, postgresql, having-clause

I am having a table *course*
and columns as *place* and *cost* with more than two rows.

I want my query to display the course which has the highest cost.
I tried with the below query

```
select splace 
from studies 
group by splace 
having max(ccost);
```

and got the error as `argument of HAVING must be type boolean, not type integer`

What mistake I have done? And What would be the correct query?

Comment: SELECT splace FROM Studies ORDER BY ccost DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: Among other things, you need `having max(ccost)` equal to something, or greater than something, etc.

Comment: You either don't need the grouping or don't need the having.  What do you actually want to achieve here?  Get the highest ccost for each splace, or get the splace with the highest cost?

Comment: The query  

select  place
from    studies
where   cost = 
        (
        select  max(cost)
        from    studies
        )

worked out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select  place
from    studies
where   cost = 
        (
        select  max(cost)
        from    studies
        )
```

Comment: What about the grouping?  This is the correct answer assuming the asker just wants the (s)place with the highest (c)cost, but not if they're trying to do something else...

Comment: If they were trying to do something else, the question would not have included, `I want my query to display the course which has the highest cost.`.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want one row, then you can use `limit` and `order by`:

```
select place
from studies
order by cost desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: If there is a tie, this approach will only show one record.

Comment: In fairness, he did say "if you only want one row" though

Comment: @DanBracuk . . . In addition, the OP describes the problem in the singular:  "I want my query to display **the course** which **has** the highest cost".